# Is mass Battlecruisers an easy win or does something counter them?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

I managed to get five bases, very well defended. However, when I got to build 20+ Battlecruisers with all armour and weapon upgrades, they literally destroyed everything (1 vs 3, Terran vs Protoss, Terran and Zerg).

They seem to be really effective if you can get heaps of resources and amass a very large fleet with only a few ravens. Nothing stands against them once you've done it. Can Battlecruisers really stand up against anything?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Bryan. If you wish to modify or expand on your question, please do so by editing it - use the "edit" link below it.

Answer (score 12):

Aside from being a very hard to press "button", making you vulnerable to just about any pressure all the time until the very late game, Battlecruisers are vulnerable to many things.

The can be picked apart by well microed Vikings, they can be cost-effectively traded for with Widow Mines, they do not do that well agains Corruptors, Fungal Growth wears them down, they are vulnerable to Feedback, Tempests do great damage to them (though can not outmicro BCs), and there's also Blink micro to pick off stray Battlecruisers.

You are making an example of situation, which can not be used to judge Battlecruisers themselves - you were terribly ahead, your teammates having bought you time to amass an maxed out army. Yes, BCs are good for such army, as they are powerful *per supply*, so you can fit many of them into 200 limit, and have powerful upgrades. But Battlecruisers are not "a win". A **maxed-out army** of expensive units against a war-torn enemy **is a win**, that is.

As Day[9] says, "*Do not think 'X will be good in this situation'. See if you are able to get X, while still in the situation it will be good for.*"

Comment: +1. If you are ahead enough to get a 200 supply max-upgrade deathball, you can build just about any units and win the game.

Comment: Also, good list of counters to BC's. Don't forget the best counter to mass-battlecruiser: attack them before they can amass a fleet!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the battlecruiser is a win 'button'. It can be easily get picked by High Templar feed backs, viking micro, and tempests are awfully good for battlecruisers